# How to modify bit of one integer from another

Tags: algorithm, bit

> Given 32 bit unsigned  integers x  and y  I would like to set bits of
> x to 1 if in corresponding position of y there is 1  without modifying
> other bits of y  So for example  if x is

1 0 0 0 0 1 etc.

and y is

0 0 0 1 0 0 etc.

> I would like a result that would be  1 0 0 1 0 1  I suppose it can be
> achieved somehow with & operator but i can not figure exactly how in
> performing way.

Thank you for help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bitwise operation "or" for this purpose:

```
unsigned int z = x | y;
```